# How can I make Python3.6, Red Hat Software Collection, persist after a reboot/logout/login?

Tags: python, linux, centos, redhat, software-collections

I am trying to enable rh-python36 software collection after reboot So I can avoid calling "scl enable" all the time.

After unzipping and installing the package:

`yum install -y tmp/rpms/*`

I created a new file "python36.sh" under /etc/profile.d with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
export X_SCLS="`scl enable rh-python36 'echo $X_SCLS'`"
```

After restarting or rebooting the instance, I am getting `: No such file or directoryenable`

I am using CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

Comment: Your solution looks right, so seems to me that something went wrong with the installation. I installed it using `yum -y install rh-python36`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the root privilege, then add the line of code below to the .bash_profile  file found in your root directory:

```
source /opt/rh/rh-python36/enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source scl_source enable rh-python36
```

Reference Doc:  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/527703

Answer (score 0):

This is the command for the Dockerfile that works for me:

```
RUN echo "source scl_source enable rh-python36" >> /etc/bashrc
```